# How to use googlecharts library in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, asset-pipeline

I want to use `googlecharts` in my rails App, and I decided use it directly without using wrapper library.

Currently I download `jsapi` file from `https://www.google.com/jsapi` and rename it to `jsapi.js`, then move the file to `vendor/javascripts/google/jsqpi.js`.

Then require the file in `application.js`.

Now I can use the library I want only to know if this is a right way to use the third party library in rails.

Is there better way than this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is perfectly acceptable.  `vendor/assets/javascripts` is the correct location for third-party javascript files.

Sometimes you can find gems that include third-party javascript libraries and integrate them into the asset pipeline for you (e.g. `jquery-ui-rails` gem).  This is nice because it makes you not responsible for handling the actual files and is easier on your version control software (a single line in your Gemfile vs entire files).  You can also update the files with bundler.  However, this tends to only be practical for really popular libraries.  Sometimes you can find gems for the javascript library you are looking for, but the gem hasn't been updated in ages.  Of course, you could always roll your own gem that includes the libraries you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [googlecharts gem](https://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts)

its full of examples

Comment: Yes, I tried the gem. It works very well at first place, but when it comes to something complex the gem is no more easy to use. I personally think so.

Comment: that is true the gem is no easier than the library